# What were Odo's "Analogies"?

Tags: ursula-k-le-guin, the-disposessed

In the book The Dispossessed there are a number of references to what's called "Odo's Analogies". The Analogies seems to be the title of perhaps a body of writing or philosophy by the character Odo, the formative thinker of the anarchist movement upon which the society of planet Anarres is based.

How much or what parts of the "Analogies" are actually known and available to readers? eg Have they ever been written or published by Ursula K. LeGuin? Or inferred in any detail from her other writings?

Comment: LeGuin was never much into fleshing out a world beyond what was needed for the story. So unless some of them are directly quoted in the book, I'm afraid you're out of luck.